# Extract SharePoint file dynamic link using Python

Tags: python, sharepoint

I am trying to scrape metadata of SharePoint files using Python from a SharePoint folder and store the data into Excel of about 5 columns.

- Columns:

1. ID
2. Created
3. Name
4. Description
5. SharePointLink

I was able to scrape first 4 columns but not SharePointLink column. It's column value should be the link when we click 'Copy Link' in the image below:
[image]

The code I am using to extract the first 4 columns is below:

```
files = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(folder_name).files
ctx.load(files).execute_query()
for file in files: 
    # print(file.properties['Name'])
    item = file.listItemAllFields
    ctx.load(item)
    ctx.execute_query()
    print(item.properties['ID'], item.properties['Created'], item.properties['Name'], item.properties['Description'])
```

Can anyone help me extract this dynamic link and store the 5 columns in an Excel within the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

The file's SharePoint URL is available in item.properties['ServerRedirectedEmbedUri'].

Update the line to,

```
print(
    item.properties['ID'],
    item.properties['Created'],
    item.properties['Name'],
    item.properties['Description'],
    item.properties['ServerRedirectedEmbedUri']
)
```

For storing the data into excel:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(fin_list)
excel_file = 'metadata.xlsx'
df.to_excel(excel_file, index=False)
```

note, fin_list is list of dictionaries.